# i faced a small issue regarding multithreading. need multithreading for computing Pi and for the Variance

Tags: c++, multithreading

**Question 1**

I want to use multithreading fir computing Pi, but first i am trying to split the job across each thread

**Question 2**

there also a piece of code down there that computes the sample variance on an array of values. I want to also to use multithread on that part of the code. The algorithm needs two passes on the data and therefore introduce a need for some sort of synchronisation (a barrier in this case).

```
// LabClass.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <process.h>  
#include <thread>
#include "Chrono.h"

//When performance is crucial, nbThreads should be the number of hardware threads supported
#define NB_THREADS  4
#define N 10000
int counter;


void HelloWorld(int id)
{
    printf("Hello world from %d\n",id);
}


void HelloCPP11()
{
    std::thread t[NB_THREADS];
    //Launch
    for (int i = 0; i < NB_THREADS; i++) 
        t[i] = std::thread(HelloWorld, i);
    //Join 
    for (int i = 0; i < NB_THREADS; i++) {
        t[i].join();
    }
}

double PIEstimateAux(int n)
{


    double sum=1;
    double div=3.;
    for (int i=0;i<n;i+=2)
    {
        sum=sum-1/div+1/(div+2);
        div+=4;

    }

        return 4*sum;
}

void PIEstimate()
{
    Chrono c;
    double val=PIEstimateAux(N);
    c.PrintElapsedTime_us("\nTime Pi (micro sec):");
    std::cout << "\nPI estimate: " << val << "\n\n";
}



double SampleVarianceAux(int *t, int n)
{
    double average=0;
    double variance=0;
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
        average+=t[i];
    average=average/(double) n;
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
        variance+=(t[i]-average)*(t[i]-average);
    variance/=(n-1.);
    return variance;
}

void SampleVariance()
{
    //creating array of random numbers
    int *t=new int[N];
    if (t==NULL)
        return ;
    for (int i=0;i<N;i++)
        t[i]=std::rand()%100;
    Chrono c;
    double val = SampleVarianceAux(t,N);
    c.PrintElapsedTime_us("Variance time (micro sec):");
    std::cout << "\nVariance estimate: " << val << "\n\n";
    delete[] t;
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    printf("\t\t\tSimple Hello world call\n");
    HelloWorld(0);
    HelloCPP11();
    PIEstimate();
    SampleVariance();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would avoid using line such as new int[N], use STL containers like vectors or list

Comment: Actually there are no questions in your code. What is the problem??

Comment: I posted the questions but ill post again

Comment: Question 1

I want to use multithreading fir computing Pi, but first i am trying to split the job across each thread

Question 2

there also a piece of code down there that computes the sample variance on an array of values. I want to also to use multithread on that part of the code. The algorithm needs two passes on the data and therefore introduce a need for some sort of synchronisation (a barrier in this case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Question 1**

You need to create `n` threads in the same manner as `HelloCPP11()` and pass `i`  to `PieEstimateAux()` as a thread ranking variable.

Use the thread ranking variable to work out the start and stop points in the for loop (eg. `start = rank * (n / # threads)` and `stop = (rank + 1) * (n / # threads)` and setup the for loop as `for(int i = start; i < stop...){}`.

Store `4 * sum` in an array for each thread and sum them in the calling function after `t[x].join()`

**Question 2**

You need to split the function as the only real barrier using this threading technique is `t[x].join()`, so you'll have to create the threads with pt1 of the function, join them, and do it again with the next part.